In which language should i write my deployment code Javascript or Solidity
Which language should I learn to write the deployment code for a smart contract: JavaScript or Solidity (using Foundry)? What should I learn according to today's trends?

This will get closed for being opinion based. If using foundry it is not really possible to avoid solidity (even if src is vyper/huff), forge-std library is in solidity and so will the tests be, can make sense to just have your deploy script in solidity as well. Then if someone else needs to work on it and they are comfortable with solidity/python, it's just as easy as for someone comfortable with solidity/javacript etc.

I can share what I use and others can give their opinion. I code both with Web3.py (Python) and use Web3.js for tests. I use Truffle for testing (Javascript) and compiling Solidity, and Ganache as my local development blockchain for testing.
I prefer Python syntax over Javascript mostly, espessially due to Javascript's lack of support for large integers and thus you'll have to convert integers to and from strings when using Javascript which you don't with Python.
